# Exception safety/handling with .Net HtmlTextWriter?

Tags: c#, .net, rollback, htmltextwriter, exception-safe

I am using a .Net `HtmlTextWriter` to generate HTML.

```
try
{
   htw.RenderBeginTag( HtmlTextWriterTag.Span );

   htw.Write(myObject.GenerateHtml());

   htw.RenderEndTag( );
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   GenerateHtmlErrorMessage(htw);
}
```

In this example, if an error exception is fired during `myObject.GenerateHtml()`, I will generate a nice error html but it will be preceded by an opening `span` tag that is never closed.

I could refactor it like so

```
try
{
   string myHtml = myObject.GenerateHtml();

   // now hope we don't get any more exceptions
   htw.RenderBeginTag( HtmlTextWriterTag.Span );
   htw.Write(myHtml)     
   htw.RenderEndTag( );
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   GenerateHtmlErrorMessage(htw);
}
```

Now my span doesn't open 'till I've done the hard work, but this just looks awkward to me. Is there any way do rollback with a HtmlWriter? Even if I had to put in loads of using blocks.

I'm currently working in .Net 2.0, but a discussion of solutions in 3.5 would be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only concerned about errors that occur during the GenerateHtml() call, and don't like the second approach (which seems fine to me), why not move the closing span tag into a finally block, and pull out the open call:

```
htw.RenderBeginTag( HtmlTextWriterTag.Span );
try
{
   htw.Write(myObject.GenerateHtml());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   GenerateHtmlErrorMessage(htw);
}
finally
{
   htw.RenderEndTag( );
}
```

This way the span is always opened and always closed. If GenerateHtml throws an exception, you catch it and generate the error inside the span, before closing it.

Of course, if the exception occurs trying to write the tags, then you are out of luck writing an error message anyway, so I'll assume that is being handled elsewhere.

Answer (score -2):

You should avoid using try/catch, and instead check if the result is not what you expected. The only thing I can see here, is that myHTML can be null, so try something like this:

string myHtml = myObject.GenerateHtml();

```
if (myHTML != null)
{
   htw.RenderBeginTag( HtmlTextWriterTag.Span );
   htw.Write(myHtml)     
   htw.RenderEndTag( );
else
{
   GenerateHtmlErrorMessage(htw);
}
```

Comment: How can I just avoid try catches when my code may throw exceptions?

Comment: You should use it only when you know that your code can go really wrong and you can´t control it, for example when connecting to a database. You can´t be sure the database is up and running, but you can see if a string is null.

When you can avoid try/catch, please do that.

Comment: I totally disagree. Avoid throwing exceptions yes, but avoid catching them?

Comment: This happens to be a really good point in my application to catch exceptions. I can both alert the user and continue in predictable manner.

Comment: Why catch them if you just can avoid having exceptions at all?

If you have a string that can be null, why try to get the value directly, instead of check if it´s null, and only get it if it´s not?

string a = null;

Console.WriteLine(a); //throws error
Console.WriteLine(a ?? String.Empty); //works

Comment: myObject.GenerateHtml() can throw many types of errors including database problems etc... All I am doing here is trying to catch the error at a point where I can let the user now that something went wrong.